# How to fetch GMail contacts in my iphone App

Tags: iphone, gmail, contacts

I need to fetch Gmail contacts by providing a gmail username and password. 
Any frameworks, Api's, Sample codes..

I know about XMPPframework that can fetch gmail chat contacts. but i want contacts from gmail address book.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Did you get success in gating the Gmail contacts? If yes then please let me know the solution .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used the Google Data Api Obj-C client (http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/). I have never used it for Contacts but it supports them. It may be a good starting point.

Comment: Hey guys this works like a charm... GData API will be for mac.. but see this link to integerate it for iOS..http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/  This is awesome.. Thanks again Felz...

Comment: how to use are you passing the usename and password or directly retrive the contact...