# How can I import contacts from gmail to iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have an app in which I need to fetch my friend's gmail id into my iPhone app. How can I import contacts from gmail to my iPhone application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the Google Contacts API for more information

http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/

Comment: Also, see this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781643/how-to-fetch-gmail-contacts-in-my-iphone-app